# How to Convert Bytearray to Plaintext?

Tags: python, aes, pycryptodome

I am trying to convert bytes to plaintext.I tried .decode() with utf-8,utf-16.
But I could not get the required text.

```
cipher = AES.new(KEY, AES.MODE_CBC,INIT_VECTOR)
decrypted_text = cipher.decrypt(cipher_text)
print("Decrypted Text:",decrypted_text)
```

**Output : Decrypted Text: b'qT]Y^YCDBQD_B\x01\x02\x03'**

Comment: The method `decode()` has nothing to do with decryption. All it does is convert `bytes`es to strings. The problem is `cipher.decrypt()` isn't producing the expected results. Without more info it's hard to be more specific, but you appear not to have the correct key for whatever is in `cipher_text`. If your code read that from a file then the first thing to check for is a trailing carriage return.

Comment: @BoarGules Thanks you for your reply.As you said,I have incorrect IV.So Only it was not returned the desired text.

Comment: also the \x02 typically come from padding bytes that you may need to unpad